# assign dynamic variable names using a loop and mutate from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to split a character field into individual variables, one for each character in a string.

```
library(dplyr)
temp1 <- data.frame(a = c('dedefdewfe' , 'rewewqreqw'))


for(i in 1:10){

  temp1 <- temp1 %>% 
    mutate(paste('v' , i , ,sep = '') = substr(a , i , i))
}
```

The resulting dataframe would have 11 variables, the original `a` , `v1` through `v10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tidyr::separate` is good for this.  You can't split on an empty string, but you can specify splitting positions ...

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
temp1 %>% 
  mutate(b=a) %>%   ## make a copy
  separate(b,into=paste0("v",1:10),sep=1:9)
```

(probably better practice to use `nc <- nchar(temp1$a[1])` and then use `nc`, `nc-1` instead of 10, 9 respectively)

Comment: you might want to consider editing your title to something like "split a character column of a data frame into multiple columns" - i.e., make it about what you're trying to accomplish rather than the particular approach